# Custom Data Table on Zedgraph

Tags: c#, markers, zedgraph

Is there any ways to add a custom data table on ZedGraph Control, I'm using two dynamic markers, when the user changes the markers and it's corresponding data point needs to be displayed.

```
// Resize The Plot Area
Rectangle rc = zedGraphControl1.Bounds;
rc.Height = Convert.ToInt32((rc.Height) * 0.85);
rc.Width = rc.Width - 10;

// Link the new phane
Graphics g = zedGraphControl1.CreateGraphics();

pane.ReSize(g, rc);
```

The above code is the sample to resize the plot area, I want to add a data table or text below the x axis.

Comment: Why don't you use a Datagridview in your From instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But the application requires a table with dotted lines, which is not possible with datagrid view.